# Selection Problem

Tags: combinations

How many ways are there to select 8 letters from 24 letters where 8 letters are 'a' ,8 letters are 'b'and rest are all unlike?

Comment: Are we selecting any random letter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Break into cases based on how many unlike letters were selected.

Supposing that you selected $k$ of the unlike letters, pick which $k$ of those they were that were selected in $\binom{8}{k}$ ways.

Then, for the remaining $8-k$ letters that you were going to select, choose how many of those will be `a`'s vs `b`'s in $8-k+1$ ways.

$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^8\binom{8}{k}(8-k+1) = 9\times 2^8 - 8\times 2^7 = 1280$$

Comment: Why are there 8-k+1 ways?

Comment: @user768300 you could have picked $0$ `a`'s, $1$ `a`'s, $2$ `a`'s, on up to $8-k$ `a`'s.  Count those... maybe start counting from $1$ and then go back once you are done and then include $0$ as well.

Comment: Perfect! Helped a lot, thanks. :D